# In Windows, open a Unix file or path

Tags: windows-10, path, clipboard

Given a clipboard holding a Unix-style path, e.g. `/c/tmp/xxx.pdf` or `/z/foo/bar/`, what might be needed to let Windows open that file or folder, `C:\tmp\xxx.pdf` or `Z:\foo\bar`, without manually changing slashes to backslashes, without manual retyping, without much mousing?

This is useful when from Windows Terminal (or putty or WSL) you ssh to a Linux server whose disk Windows mounts.  In ssh, you find a Unix path, click-drag to copy it to the clipboard. Back in Windows you logo+E alt+D to open File Explorer, *(do something, maybe a hotkey that launches some kind of script?),* and then ctrl+V paste what File Explorer can understand.

(Many questions and answers post how to do the reverse, e.g. https://github.com/clechasseur/pathcopycopy.)

Comment: You'd need some sort of macro or running application to change these values to something Windows recognizes. This constrains your prospective workflow to solve this. Perhaps something using AutoHotKey that, on a keypress, reads the clipboard, modifies it, and then places that new value into the clipboard to be pasted where you wish? This could then be accessed via a hot key, allowing you to press CTRL+C, the AHK hot key sequence, and then CTRL+V to paste.

Comment: BTW, Windows can be somewhat forgiving of using a *forward* slash in a path, e.g., `cd C:/windows` works in CMD. Even `cd c:/program files/7-zip`, with a space in the folder name, and *without* quotes works! Test on your system to see how much edting of the path is needed.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Yes!  With `/`'s, File Explorer won't autocomplete, but it *will* accept and open a pasted path.

Comment: A quick test on this Windows 10 PC showed `cd c:/pro*` opened *Program Files* - note that it simply took the first match, without user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

Given a clipboard holding `/r/foo` or `/r/foo/bar.txt`, invoking this [Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com) script with Win+F converts it to `r:\foo` or `r:\foo\bar.txt`, and then opens it with File Explorer for a folder, or Windows' default handler for a file with that extension (say, Notepad for `.txt`).  It fails for paths containing whitespace, but Unix culture avoids those anyways.

```
#SingleInstance force
SendMode Input
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir% ; Consistent starting directory.
#f:: ; Invoke with Win+f, replacing Windows' hotkey for feedback.

XX := Clipboard
; replace /r/with r, then with r:\
XX := SubStr(Trim(XX), 2)
XX := Strreplace(XX, "/", ":\", 0, 1)

XX := Strreplace(XX, "/", "\")
Run "C:\Windows\explorer.exe" %XX%
return
```